# Unlocking a field based on a security role in CRM Dynamics via TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamics-crm

I'm very new to Typescript. Below I'm creating a function for Dynamics CRM 365. I want to achieve the following unlock a field when the user role is equal to or has role of `Business Advisor`

or if their is a easier way to do this please point me towards the right direction to, maybe it might not be a good idea to do foreach loops. Please see logic below

let formContext: Xrm.FormContext = null;
let isBusinessAdvisorRole = null;

```
export function checkBusinessAdvisorRole() {

var businessAdvisorRole = "Business Advisor role";
isBusinessAdvisorRole = false;

    //Store Security Roles
    var userRoles = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.roles;
    var hasRole = false;

    //I want to do a foreach here over user roles
    //Then do
    //if user role = "Business Advisor role"
    //formContext.getControl<Xrm.Controls.StringControl>("fsdyn_name").setDisabled(false);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how the script might look like:

```
export function checkBusinessAdvisorRole(executionContext: Xrm.Events.EventContext) {
    const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

    const roles = ["Business Advisor role", "System Administrator"];

    //Store Security Roles
    const userRoles = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.roles;
    const hasRole = userRoles.get().some(r => roles.indexOf(r.name) != -1);

    formContext.getControl<Xrm.Controls.StringControl>("fsdyn_name").setDisabled(!hasRole);
}
```

Comment: clean as always Andrew!

Comment: I love TS. Much cleaner than JS. But in JS it would look clean as well. Array selectors are a blessing for C# developers who knows LINQ 2 Objects :)

Comment: @AndrewButenko What if I need to do || System admin || Sales Advisor, most convenient way to do || conditions?